# findViewById returns null altough ID of the component exists

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I defined `ListView` in xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/optionList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/option_array"  
 />
```

Inside corresponding class I call:

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.optionList);
        Log.d("LISTA", list + "");//it's null
```

but I get null on the `list` variable. I do not understand why. How to correct it? I can't add listener to that list if I get null.

Full class code:

```
package com.example.smbp1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class OptionListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_option_list);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        createListeners();
    }

    private void createListeners() {

        final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.optionList);
        Log.d("LISTA", list + "");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option_list,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


}
```

Activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.smbp1.OptionListActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.smbp1.OptionListActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/optionList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/option_array"  
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option_list, container, false);
    final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.optionList);
    Log.d("LISTA", list + "");
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String element = list.getSelectedItem() + "";
            Log.d("Item", element);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Obvious question... you have called `setContentView` BEFORE this, correct?

Comment: Please post `res/layout/activity_option_list` in its entirety.

Comment: In the Eclipse menu -> `Project -> Clean`. This will remove all generated files, and rebuild the application. This fixes many issues with `R` related issues.

Comment: what is the name of the xml layout file where `optionList` is located?

Comment: @singularhum It is called `fragment_option_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `optionList` is located in a fragment so accessing it must be done in it as well.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_option_list,
                container, false);

        // here as an example
        final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.optionList);
        Log.d("LISTA", list + "");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post very complete code, but perhaps you are calling this in onCreate() or onAttach() something that happens before onCreateView()? The view you are looking inside is probably still null.

Comment: Yes I do in which method I suppose to add this listener?

Comment: on onCreateView() after you call super() or setContentView()... only *then* can you look for child views.

Comment: onCreateView() is in different static class I call it after setContentView(); please have a glance at code in the and of OP.

Comment: You really should be doing view related stuff in the Fragment, not the Activity. If at all possible, move the code related to the ListView into the OnCreateView() section of the Fragment!